# Resolve dependencies when calling constructor using DI with ASP.NET 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

The web seems flooded with examples on how to use DI with ASP.NET 5 but not one of the examples shows how to call a constructor and resolve dependencies.

The following is just one of many cases:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/28875.dependency-injection-in-asp-net-vnext.aspx

But what happens if I want to do the following:

```
var todoRepository = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<ITodoRepository>();
ToDoController controller = new TodoController(todoRepository);
```

Presumably this can be shorted to something like...

```
.Get<TodoController>()
```

Like you can in Ninject.

Can someone explain how this can be done?

Comment: Isn't that against the whole idea of DI?  Wouldn't the controllers be registered as services as well as the repository?  I would have thought you'd get an instance of the controller in the same way...

Comment: You will never call the constructor of a Controller when using DI. The Resolve-Method must take care of everything.

Comment: The whole thing about DI with containers like ninject and unity is *not* to write any `new`. (as long as we ignore Model-Classes)

Comment: That's what I thought but I can't see any examples showing how to do this, in the examples a controller is used, however I have an MvcHandler which requires the IApplicationBuilder interface to be injected into the constructor and I'm still non the wiser on how the code should look so could you give an example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'll want to make sure the class you want to construct is registered with the DI container. (Given your example of a controller, it probably already is thanks to the MVC framework.)

There's several ways to do this, the most basic of which is registering a Transient.  Note this needs to be done in the `ConfigureServices` stage of your `Startup` class.

```
services.AddTransient<ToDoController>();
```

Once you have it registered, you can resolve it just like you would any other service:

```
app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<ToDoController>();
```

For more information, I'd recommend [Victor Hurdugaci's blog on Dependency Injection in ASP.NET vNext](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/06/17/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-vnext.aspx). It was written for alpha, but it looks like it's still accurate.

Comment: On the basis of your example, does ToDoController implement ITodoRepository or does ToDoController have a constructor which requires an argument which implements ITodoRepository?

Comment: Just as your example, `ToDoController` has a constructor with one argument: `public ToDoConstructor(ITodoRepository repo)`.

Comment: So in that case to call the constructor I need to execute app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<ToDoController>(); ?