# Dependency injection inside a FilterAttribute in ASP.NET MVC 6

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, filter, dependency-injection

I'm struggling with ASP.NET MVC 6 (beta 4 release) trying to inject a service within a controller filter attribute of type `AuthorizationFilterAttribute`.

This is the service (it has another service injected)

```
public class UsersTableRepository
{
    private readonly NeurosgarContext _dbContext;

    public UsersTableRepository(NeurosgarContext DbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = DbContext;
    }

    public ICollection<User> AllUsers
    {
        get
        {
            return _dbContext.Users.ToList();
        }
    }

    //other stuff...
}
```

This is the ConfigureServices method in Startup class for services enabling

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
        //...

        services.AddSingleton<NeurosgarContext>(a => NeurosgarContextFactory.GetContext());
        services.AddSingleton<UifTableRepository<Nazione>>();
        services.AddSingleton<UsersTableRepository>();
  }
```

A simple "dummy" controller with two filters defined on it. You can notice that I already done DI inside this controller by decorating the property with `[FromServices]`and it works.

```
[Route("[controller]")]
[BasicAuthenticationFilter(Order = 0)]
[BasicAuthorizationFilter("Admin", Order = 1)]
public class DummyController : Controller
{

    [FromServices]
    public UsersTableRepository UsersRepository { get; set; }

    // GET: /<controller>/
    [Route("[action]")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Doing the same DI within `BasicAuthenticationFilter`does not work and at runtime `UserRepository` property is a null reference.

```
public class BasicAuthenticationFilterAttribute : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
{
    [FromServices]
    public UsersTableRepository UsersRepository { get; set; }

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)

    {
        if (!Authenticate(filterContext.HttpContext))
        {
            // 401 Response
            var result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
            // Add the header for Basic authentication require
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Append("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic");
            filterContext.Result = result;

            //if (!HasAllowAnonymous(context))
            //{
            //    base.Fail(context);
            //}
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

Any idea about how solve this?

Answer (score 8):

Refrain from injecting dependencies into your attributes as explained [here](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=98). Make your [attributes passive](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/13/passive-attributes/), or make your attribute a [humble object](http://xunitpatterns.com/Humble%20Object.html) as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29915192/unity-property-injection-on-authorizeattribute/29916075#29916075).

Comment: The problem is that if I use a constructor in the filter to inject the service I can't intercept the attribute instance.

Comment: That's because you shouldn't inject dependencies into your attributes. Please read the referenced articles closely.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var dependencyScope = context.HttpContext.RequestServices;
    var usersRepository = dependencyScope.GetService(typeof(UsersTableRepository)) as UsersTableRepository;
    // usersRepository is now ready to be used
```

So your BasicAuthenticationFilter will look like this:

```
public class BasicAuthenticationFilterAttribute : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
{
    public UsersTableRepository UsersRepository { get; set; }

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)

    {
        var dependencyScope = context.HttpContext.RequestServices;
        UsersRepository = dependencyScope.GetService(typeof(UsersTableRepository)) as UsersTableRepository;
        
        if (!Authenticate(filterContext.HttpContext))
        {
            // 401 Response
            var result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
            // Add the header for Basic authentication require
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Append("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic");
            filterContext.Result = result;

            //if (!HasAllowAnonymous(context))
            //{
            //    base.Fail(context);
            //}
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```