# How do I enable property injection for filters with LightInject?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, light-inject

I have an authentication filter that I want to inject with the authentication source. I'm using light inject and I have `EnableAnnotatedPropertyInjection()` enabled on the container, `[Inject]` above the property of the filter, and the type of he property, `RegisterInstance<IMyAuth>()`, registered and being injected into other controllers in my solution. What are the requirements for having LightInject perform property injection on a `IAuthenticationFilter`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30096903/dependency-injection-inside-a-filterattribute-in-asp-net-mvc-6